# PHP - When I include my html files into the php files, then click a link the pages are stacking?

Tags: php, html, include

So like the title says I use `include_once('core_tpl/some_file.tpl');` to include the html.

The problem I'm having is when I click one of the links inside `some_file.tpl`, the file that should be loading is stacking below the current page.

Help please!
Cheers.

Codes like this:

```
  <?php
  class shop{
    public function action(){
       include_once('core_tpl/header.tpl');
       include_once('core_tpl/TPL/shop_number.tpl');
       include_once('core_tpl/footer.tpl');
    }
  }
  $index = new shop();
  $index->action();
  ?>
```

Comment: I assume this is more HTML issue. If you also using a framework, which is that?

Comment: It's my own framework. Hmmm it could be a HTML issue but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Clicking any of the links from `some_file.tpl` behaves the same or only specific links?

Comment: By _stacking_ do you mean it loads under what is already rendered? Are you using ajax to bypass the default anchor behaviour to fill etc. a div by clicking? (html/js code is needed in that case)

Comment: Yes any of the links from some_file.tpl behaves the same. Yes by stacking i meant it loads under what's already rendered, no there isn't any ajax. Thanks for this btw guys.